# (Android Studio -Java)El intent me ejecuta google maps en segundo plano, no se ve, creia que no funcionaba y lo vi al darle a la flecha atras, porque?

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, procesos-en-segundo-plano

Cuando en el emulador le doy para atras y sale de la app, aparece google maps, quiero que se ejecute directamente y no en segundo plano, como?

```
           case R.id.ItemMaps:
               Intent mapIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:39.94409963458733, -0.10325612017290911"));
               mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
               startActivity(mapIntent);

           case R.id.ItemWeb:
               Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
               webIntent.setData(Uri.parse(mi_url));
               startActivity(webIntent);
```

Comment: Lo que mencionas es imposible, a menos que estés realizando otro intent, agrega tu código completo por favor.

Comment: Lo primero gracias @Jorgesys, he dado con el fallo, era tan fácil como ponerle los "break;" y casi me vuelvo loco, es lo que tenemos los principiantes...

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes un `Switch`, debes agregar en cada condición, pero debe finalizar con `break;` , ´

```
...
...
  case R.id.ItemMaps:
               Intent mapIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:39.94409963458733, -0.10325612017290911"));
               mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
               startActivity(mapIntent);

               break; 

           case R.id.ItemWeb:
               Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
               webIntent.setData(Uri.parse(mi_url));
               startActivity(webIntent);

               break; 
...
...
```

esto para detener la ejecución, de otra forma se llamarán todas las opciones dentro del `Switch